# How to determine if the column space of two matrices are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a matrix A and B, it can be shown that if the two matrices are row equivalent, then their row spaces are the same.

Since there is a connection between the row space and column space of a matrix (row space of A = column space of transpose of A), I was wondering if there was a way to determine if the column spaces of two matrices are the same similar to above for row spaces.

Comment: Well, if the transposes of two matrices are row equivalent, the transposes have the same row space. But the rows of the transposes are the columns of original matrices. So the original matrices have the same column space. Note that the condition "transposes are row equivalent" is rephrased as "the matrices are column equivalent". Row equivalence of transposes is equivalent to column equivalence of original matrices.